# dynamic change jwplayer video path

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jwplayer

basically i wish to achieve like user type file name,then video will be pop up

what i want to do is i was tried to pass textbox value as jwplayer path to play video

if i typed Video/video.mp3 into textbox and i click "button" , my jwplayer able to play video.mp3

what i want to do is juz typed "video" then jwplayer able to starts

by doing that i plan to use database to do checking

once user type video, then database will return jwplayer/video.mp3 and pass the value to jwplayer script, but i cant achieve that!

**javascript**

```
    function playSelected() {
        var a = document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;

        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
            file: a,
            image: "jwplayer/preview.jpg"
        });
    }
```

**button**

```
<input type="button" runat="server" value="Click me!" onclick='playSelected()'>
```

**textbox**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare in javascript

`var a = "video/" + document.GetElementbyID("textbox2").value + ".mp3";`

Then you only have to input the video name alone and the rest is added dynamically.

Comment: i got others file format as well,as this cases what should i do?

Comment: You could create a loop that checks against each file type to see if the file exists in folder videos and then set that as `var a`

Comment: aiks, any example can refer?i am failed to do the checking

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `load` method to dynamically load a movie. Here's a full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>jwplayer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mediaplayer">JW Player goes here</div>

    <input type="text" id="TextBox2" value="video.mp4" />
    <input type="button" onclick="playSelected()" value="Play" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            image: "preview.jpg"
        });

        var playSelected = function () {
            var movie = document.getElementById('TextBox2').value;
            jwplayer().load(movie).play();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi darin, my problem is i got different format video as well but not only 1 format,in this cases what should i do?